# Synchronize 2 Select2 elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```
 $("#s1").select2(options1);
 $("#s2").select2(options2);

 $("#s1").on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
   // doSomethingThatSynchronizesS1withS2();
 });
```

I have two select2 elements, that I want to keep synchronized. Thus, every time I select a value in one of these elements, I want the other one to have the exact same value selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a callback method on `select2:selecting`, you need to have a callback method on `change` event.

When you change `s1` element, you need to get the selected values of the s1 element and then update `s2` element using those values. This will sync s2 with s1.

```
        $('#s1').on('change', function (e) {
              var selectedValues = $(this).val();  //Get the selected Values
              $('#s2').val(selectedValues);        //Update S2 with selected values.
        });
```

You need to have similar callback method to sync s1 with s2 as well.

This would update the values in both the select boxes. However, as you would notice this would not get reflected in the UI. To get the selected values reflected in the UI you would need to manually trigger the change method like below:

```
        $('#s1').on('change', function (e) {
              var selectedValues = $(this).val();  //Get the selected Values
              $('#s2').val(selectedValues);        //Update S2 with selected values.
              $('#s2').trigger('change');          //Trigger the change event to reflect values.
        });

        $('#s2').on('change', function (e) {
              var selectedValues = $(this).val();  //Get the selected Values
              $('#s1').val(selectedValues);        //Update S1 with selected values.
              $('#s1').trigger('change');          //Trigger the change event to reflect values.
        });
```

This is where it gets tricky. Within the change event of s1 you are manually triggering the change event of s2 and within the change event of s2 you are again triggering the change event of s1. This results in a never ending loop. To fix this we can use another variable `triggerManual`. Below is the whole code

```
        $("#s1").select2();
        $("#s2").select2();
        var triggerManual = false; //use this variable to avoid never ending loop.
        $('#s1').on('change', function (e) {
              if( triggerManual ) {
                return;
              }
              var selectedValues = $(this).val();
              $('#s2').val(selectedValues);
              changeSelValues();
        });

        $('#s2').on('change', function (e) {
              if( triggerManual ) {
                return;
              }
              var selectedValues = $(this).val();
              $('#s1').val(selectedValues);
              changeSelValues();
        }); 

        function changeSelValues() {
            triggerManual = true; //set the global variable as true.
            $('#s1').trigger('change');
            $('#s2').trigger('change');

            triggerManual = false; //set it again to false
        }
```

The value gets updated when you select or deselect any value in s1 and vice-versa.

You can check the demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh71m25y/1/)

Comment: Alternatively, to avoid endless recursion one can use extraParameters: `$('#s1').trigger('change',{manual: true});` and `$("#s1").on("change",function(e,extraParam) { if (!extraParam.manual) { /** doSynchronization()**/ }});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#s1').change(function(e, data){
    if (!data?.programmaticTrigger) {
        $('#s2').trigger('change', {
            programmaticTrigger: true
        });
    }
});

$('#s2').change(function(e, data){
    if (!data?.programmaticTrigger) {
        $('#s1').trigger('change', {
            programmaticTrigger: true
        });
    }
});
```